# If an Angular 2 project is hosted and running on a server, can we download just HTML and make the changes and view them?

Tags: html, angular, webserver, angular2-build

In other words.. if i make changes to just the HTML without pulling down the whole project, will that change be reflected? Is that possible?

I would like to know if it is possible to do that without having to follow the normal process ...
 make appropriate HTML change -> build project and upload dist folder onto the server ..?

Comment: **which** HTML? How is the project built and bundled. And most importantly, why don't you deploy the app on your own machine during development?

Comment: I usually do that i.e  deploy on own machine during development.... but the requirement is to not download any folders to own machine .. instead make changes to the HTML files in that project , while project is still on the sever.. is that possible?